# Throttle messaging in Firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have 1M+ devices registered. Is there a way to limit how quickly the messages get delivered? Obviously it's real hard to scale if 1M+ notifications at the exact same time cause a massive spike of traffic to your backend. Would be great if instead of all the messages getting delivered immediately to all devices, you could make it only send X messages per second.

Comment: That's certainly some logic that you could code up on your own.  The FCM won't do that for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson I believe that this is pretty essential for many. I believe that there should be some reusable codes or libraries already implemented this. Have you ever heard something related to this?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for external resources.  Questions that do so are likely to get closed as off-topic.  But if you feel this is a missing feature in FCM, please feel free to file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Yeah, file an issue than nobody would take with you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're suggesting.  The bugs and features filed are taken seriously.  If there's enough demand for a feature, there is a chance it will get implemented.  But the demand has to be expressed.

Comment: If you use FCM topics, they are built with a fanout so that messages are sent in batches, thus eliminating the worry of them all being sent at one time.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have filed many issues and never seen that an issue is considered seriously. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/137 Here is one of my issue. You can see that there is demand but nothing yet. Sending a bug or feature in a private way like email or contact form is the worst way to file an issue since nobody can see the progress until it will be delivered.

Comment: @JenPerson Thank you. I am considering a couple of function to address this issue as you suggested.

Comment: In that issue you linked, Google employees did respond and take it seriously.  It will sometimes require patience to wait for new work to be scheduled and completed, as every issue has to be prioritized against other issues.  It can't hurt to file the feature request, but if you don't file it at all, your voice simply won't be heard as loudly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control the delivery of those message is actually by calling FCM with the token IDs yourself, preferably with the [batched delivery feature from the legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) (look for the `registration_ids` parameter there). You can scale this up to as many calls to the API as you need to deliver your message to all devices.

Using topics is also possible, but you lose control of the delivery performance since the fan-out happens in a process you don't control.

Alternatively: consider sending a data message that contains a timestamp on when it should be displayed. That way you separate the delivery time from the display time, removing the critical path (but of course introducing other considerations).

Comment: I noticed legacy API but made me afraid of to be removed in near future. Is there any plan to remove it near future? The alternative idea seems interesting. I will check as well.

Comment: There are no plans to remove it in the nearby future.